# Get content between parenthesis from String object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string like this:

`Hi my name is John (aka Johnator)`.

What is the best way to get what comes between the parentheses (including the parentheses)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with a regular expression:

```
a = "Hi my name is John (aka Johnator)"
a[/\(.*?\)/]
# => "(aka Johnator)"
```

Comment: what do you get for `"Hi my name is John (aka Surprise Bat /\\(*)(*)/\\)"`?

Comment: @dbenhur half a Surprise Bat. `[/\(.*\)/]` will prevent the slaughter.

Comment: @Cade ok, but now we're hosed with `"Hi my name is John (aka Surprise Bat /\\(*)(*)/\\) and this is my friend William (aka Bill)"`. Regexp has a hard time with arbitrary nesting http://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/1074296.

Comment: @dbenhur Sure. But these are straw men. It also won't help with `(It's () hard () to () write () a ()( (regex) )() when () the () input () (can () be () anything!))`

Comment: @venkatareddy The question mark changes it from a greedy match, which will match until the last closing parenthesis, to a lazy match, which will match until the first closing parenthesis. You can read more about greedy vs. lazy matching here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy

Answer (score 3):

Use `[^()]*?` for select text in parenthese :

```
a = "Hi (a(b)c) ((d)"
# => "Hi (a(b)c) ((d)"
a.gsub(/\([^()]*?\)/) { |x| p x[1..-2]; "w"}
"b"
"d"
# => "Hi (awc) (w"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str1 = ""
text = "Hi my name is John (aka Johnator)"

text.sub(/(\(.*?\))/) { str1 = $1 }

puts str1
```

Edit: Didn't read about leaving the parenthesis!